# Should the "Update for the .NET Framework 4" be deployed to servers?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 installs something called the "Update for the .NET Framework 4".  There is also a separate download for this update here: [Update for the .NET Framework 4](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2468871)

Should this update be installed on our servers as well (which host Asp.net/.Net 4.0 based websites)? Or is this update only applicable to Visual Studio related issues?

After installing VS 2010 SP1 I do not see a new option in Visual Studio for targeting an updated .Net 4.0 Framework version. Also in IIS I do not see an option for choosing an updated version of the .Net 4.0 Framework.

Also if the answer is "Yes, you should install this update on your servers", is this update backwards compatible with sites that were built not using the update?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if only for the `SmtpClient` fix:

> This update replaces the following
>   hotfixes:
>
> > [2183292](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2183292) FIX: "Failure sending mail"
> >     error message when you send an email
> >     message by using a .NET Framework
> >     4-based application that uses the
> >     "System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient" class if
> >     the email attachment is larger than 3
> >     MB q